# How to Override phtml file in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, theme, overrides, phtml

I am overwriting

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attributes.phtl
```

and I tried puting the overriden file in two locations but no chages occur

First:

```
app/code/<VENDOR_NAME/<MODULE_NAME>/view/frontend/templates/product/attributes.phtml
```

Having created a module here

Second:

```
app/design/frontend/<VENDOR_NAME>/<THEME_NAME>/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For an override to happen in a module the path needs to be `app/code/{vendor}` not `app/{vendor}`. That might just be a typo in the question though.

Comment: @circlesix Yes, it is a typo in the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- **Override `attributes.phtml` with theme**

**Copy From**

`vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml`

**To**

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml

- **Override `attributes.phtml` with custom module**

Create `catalog_product_view.xml` at

> app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.attributes">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Prince_Test::product/view/attributes.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now copy `attributes.phtml` to

> app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml

**Now flush cache.**

Comment: I thought that for the overriding templates I needed to only edit it from here 
`app/design/frontend/<VENDOR_NAME>/<THEME_NAME>/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attributes.phtl`
and that for overriding layouts I needed to have a catalog_product_view.xml file. 
Thank you, it finally worked!

Comment: Your welcome @KonstantinPatroev

Comment: @PrincePatel is the `referenceblock` name anything specific or can it be anything?

Comment: @JurģisTomsLiepiņš referenceBlock in override file must have the same block name as base file.