# How can I override attributes.phtml file?

Tags: magento2

I want to override `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml` file in my theme.

I've tried putting it in `app/code/Infortis/Ultimo/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml`

but that doesn't do anything at all

I've also tried `app/design/frontend/Infortis/ultimo/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml`

but this just creates a duplicate file in `var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/app/design/frontend/Infortis/ultimo/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml`

instead of overriding the file in `var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml`

Any help is very appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `attributes.phtml` with theme
Copy From

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml

To

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml

Create `catalog_product_view.xml` at

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.attributes">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/view/attributes.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/213014/how-to-override-phtml-file-in-magento-2

Comment: I'll try this, Prashant. 

I did not see that question, Jugal, I tried searching before creating my question.